# How to make horizontal sections on a homepage in Blogger?

Tags: html, css, blogger

[Here is a reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnil4.jpg)

I would like to make a homepage with separate sections like the above on a Blogger Website.
Can I use flexbox to do this and if I can, how can I incorporate it into the built-in theme in Blogger?
What code do I have to change and where?

If you can post any helpful links or videos, I would really appreciate it

Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

If you can edit the css or insert own customized css for your Blogger page you can easily make your section parent element `width: 100%` of the window. Then all the children of that element, which are your sections, you can flex and apply customized style to them. Hard to say exactly how you'd do it when I have no knowledge how Blogger works, but I'll show you a example of how to accomplish this. Study the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/q2v64kof/1/